# Are intervally constant analytic functions always constant?

Tags: analysis

Does a real analytic function $f:R→R$ being constant in some open interval implies that it is constant in the whole domain?

If so, how to prove it? Otherwise, is there any counter-example?

Comment: It is true under the hypothesis that the domain is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $f$ is constant on an open-bounded interval $I$ implies its derivative $f'$, which is also an analytic function, is zero on $I$, an open domain. By the principle of isolated zeros, $f'$ is identically zero on $\mathbb R$, and $f$ is constant.

Comment: It's quite an concise answer.
I'm also wondering if I only have infinitely differentiable $f$, will the implication still holds?

Comment: Try the function defined for positive $x$ by $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$ and for non-positive $x$ by $f(x) = 0$. One can show by induction that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, and constant (equal to $0$) on $(-\infty,0)$ ; yet, it is not constant.