# Is a Maclaurin series in an interval that doesn't include $0$ unique?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, power-series

In interval q, $0\notin q$, ( e.g.[1,2] ), $   \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n} $ converge to $0$. Can there be an $a_i$ that $a_i \ne 0$?

p.s I know the case when $0 \in q$, where you can prove it by derivative.

p.p.s  I asked the question in mathoverflow(now I know it is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research.).

it seems it

> follows from the uniqueness theorem for holomorphic functions

?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What does it mean that a power series “converges at $0$ in $[1, 2]$”?

Comment: oh! sorry, it should be converge to $0$.

Comment: Do you mean for a given $x$ it converges to zero or for all $x$ it converges to zero?

Comment: If the former, of course not. If the latter (working where the series uniformly converges), of course yes - you can check it by taking derivatives to extract the coefficients to see that they're all zero.

Comment: If I've interpreted your question correctly, you're asking whether a power series can be constant (e.g. $0$) for all $x$ in an (open, bounded) interval, yet not necessarily identically constant outside of the interval. The answer is shown to be a negative in [question 2676022](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676022/are-intervally-constant-analytic-functions-always-constant). An analytic function that is constant on an open, bounded interval is constant everywhere.

Comment: That should solves it, but can you elaborate that if an analytic function is zero on $I$, an open domain. By the principle of isolated zeros, $f$ is identically zero on $R$? ...............I googled it, but if the zeroes are not isolated, couldn't it just be a small interval around $z_0$ converge to $0$ instead of the whole $(-R,R)$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I mean all x in the interval q converges to $0$, and I wonder if other x in the Radius of convergence converges to $0$ too.

Comment: If it is zero on an interval, e.g. every $x$ in $(1,2)$, then every $x$ in that interval is a zero of the function. But that means that the zeroes *aren't* isolated - there's infinitely many of them, all bunched together in $(1,2)$. If $f$ is analytic, this can only be the case if $f$ is constant [(proof on Proofwiki)](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zeroes_of_Analytic_Function_are_Isolated).

Comment: It doesn't matter how big the interval is, it could be $(1,1+\varepsilon)$ for any tiny $\varepsilon$ because there are still infinitely many points (and thus, zeroes) in the interval: $\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right),\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\right),\ldots$.

Comment: But what happens in (-1,1)? The series is also converges at there.

Comment: The same thing happens. Why would you expect $(-1,1)$ to be different?

Comment: @Jam: Because according to the assumption, you don't know if there is any zeroes in $(-1,1)$. if $f(1) = 0$, then $f$ converge to $0$ in $|x-1| < R$, but you still don't know about $(-1, 1-R)$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is zero for all $x$ in an interval, e.g., $(1, 2)$ or $(1, 1.000\ldots01)$, then it is zero everywhere else in $\mathbb{R}$, including all $x$ in $(-1,1)$. We derived this fact, despite it not being an assumption. I'm confused by how you're using "$R$" - is it a particular real number? It normally denotes the set of *all* real numbers.

Comment: @Jam: I'm using it as radius of convergence, like it's in the proof on proofwiki. I probably  should read a complex analysis book to find the answer. thx